# Populating D3 chart with external JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a D3 chart created. Currently the data populating the chart is on the same html page. Going forward the data for this chart will be populated by an external JSON file. The JSON is created by values entered into a form. When I try to replace the “hard coded” data with the d3.json function I completely destroy the chart, could anyone suggest where I’m going wrong?
Current files:

Chart.html

```
<script>
var data = [
    {key: "ING_SW_CB",      value: 10 },
    {key: "SB_SW_CB",            value: 9 },
    {key: "NG3_SW_CB",       value: 8 },
    {key: "Mould_Close",        value: 12 },
    {key: "Leak_Test",          value: 10 },
    {key: "ML_Load",            value: 7 },
    {key: "Pre_Heat",           value: 12 },
    {key: "Dispense",           value: 10 },
    {key: "A310",                   value: 10 },
    {key: "Gelation",               value: 11 },
    {key: "Platen",                 value: 9 },
    {key: "Mainline_Unload",  value: 13},
    {key: "De_mould",           value: 10},
    {key: "Clean_Up",           value: 11},
    {key: "Soda_Blast",             value: 12},
    {key: "Miscellaneous",       value: 12}
];
var w = 800;
var h = 450;
var margin = {
top: 58,
bottom: 100,
left: 80,
right: 40
};
var width = w - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(data.map(function(entry){
        return entry.key;
    }))
    .rangeBands([0, width],.2);
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
        return d.value;
    })])
    .range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()   
                  .scale(x)
                  .orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(y)
                  .orient("left");
var yGridLines = d3.svg.axis()
                         .scale(y)
                         .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
                         .tickFormat("")
                         .orient("left");
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("id", "chart")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);
var chart = svg.append("g")
        .classed("display", true)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top +           ")");

function plot(params){
this.append("g")
     .call(yGridLines)
     .classed("gridline", true)
     .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
this.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(params.data)
    .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .classed("bar", true)
        .attr("x", function (d,i){
            return x(d.key);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d,i){
            return y(d.value);
        })
        .attr("height", function(d,i){
            return height - y(d.value);
        })
        .attr("width", function(d){
            return x.rangeBand();
        });
this.selectAll(".bar-label")
    .data(params.data)
    .enter()
        .append("text")
        .classed("bar-label", true)
        .attr("x", function(d,i){
            return x(d.key) + (x.rangeBand()/2)
        })
        .attr("dx", 0)
        .attr("y", function(d,i){
            return y(d.value);
        })
        .attr("dy", -6)
        .text(function(d){
            return d.value;
        })
this.append("g")
     .classed("x axis", true)
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + height + ")")
     .call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("text")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("dx", -8)
                .attr("dy" ,8)
                .attr("transform", "translate(0,0) rotate(-45)");

this.append("g")
     .classed("y axis", true)
     .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
     .call(yAxis);

this.select(".y.axis")
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-50," + height/2 + ") rotate(-90)")
    .text("Downtime [Hrs]");

this.select(".x.axis")
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + ",80)")
    .text("[Stations]");    
    // title 
this.append("text")
    .attr("x", (width / 2))             
    .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
    .style("font-size", "16px") 
    .style("text-decoration", "underline")  
    .text("Over Mould");    
}
plot.call(chart, {data: data});
</script>
```

I wish to replace the "data" var with this external JSON file:

```
[
  [
    {
        "key": "ING_SW_CB",
        "value": "5"
    },
    {
        "key": "SB_SW_CB",
        "value": "5"
    },
    {
        "key": "NG3_SW_CB",
        "value": "5"
    },
    {
        "key": "Mould_Close",
        "value": "5"
    },
    {
        "key": "Leak_Test",
        "value": "5"
    },
    {
        "key": "ML_Load",
        "value": "5"
    },
    {
        "key": "Pre_Heat",
        "value": "5"
    },
    {
        "key": "Dispense",
        "value": "5"
    },
    {
        "key": "A310",
        "value": "5"
    },
    {
        "key": "Gelation",
        "value": "5"
    },
    {
        "key": "Platen",
        "value": "5"
    },
    {
        "key": "Mainline_Unload",
        "value": "5"
    },
    {
        "key": "De_mould",
        "value": "5"
    },
    {
        "key": "Clean_Up",
        "value": "5"
    },
    {
        "key": "Soda_Blast",
        "value": "5"
    },
    {
        "key": "Miscellaneous",
        "value": "5"
    }
  ]
]
```

I really appreciate your time, I’m on a deadline to have this up & running!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json file is malformated. It's overly nested:

```
[
  [
   ...
  ]
]
```

See: http://plnkr.co/edit/QDiAgFfPpRoXRdvexREF?p=preview

Comment: Thank you Tony! so I need to alter my PHP script sort out the nesting? Thanks for the plunker example, this really helps.

Comment: @PajoHackman Just be sure that whatever you're drawing/acting on is an array of objects: `[ Object, Object, ...]`. Otherwise, you'll have to account for the extra nesting, something like: `data[0].map(...)`.

Comment: Thank you so much Tony, I managed to remove a layer of nesting in my PHP script and now have the format [{...}, {...}, {...}]

Answer (score 0):

The following URL will help you to check the validity of your JSON. http://jsonlint.com/